# Getting data from JSON Object

Tags: php, json

```
$response = '{"items":
     [{"id":"1","food":"rice","Amount":"100","condition":"paid"},\
      {"id":"2","food":"beans","Amount":"200","condition":"paid"},\
      {"id":"3","food":"yam","Amount":"50","condition":"not paid"},\
      {"id":"4","food":"tomatoes","Amount":"100","condition":"paid"},\
      {"id":"5","food":"potato","Amount":"700","condition":"paid"}]}';

echo $response['items'][1]['food'];
```

> Error: "Illegal string offset 'items'

Why can't I access the data?

Comment: Did you decode the string with json_decode first? Your question does not show it

Comment: I printed the string before and after decoding it, no difference.

Comment: can you look at my answer?

Comment: Spot on Andreas, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must decode a json string before using it as an object/array.
Your question shows you want to use it as an array, that means the second parameter of json_decode should be true.
However the `\` makes your string invalid. Is that copy paste error or is that the actual string?
If it is the actual string then you may need to remove the `\` before decoding.
I assume it's  a copy paste error?

```
$response = '{"items":
     [{"id":"1","food":"rice","Amount":"100","condition":"paid"},
      {"id":"2","food":"beans","Amount":"200","condition":"paid"},
      {"id":"3","food":"yam","Amount":"50","condition":"not paid"},
      {"id":"4","food":"tomatoes","Amount":"100","condition":"paid"},
      {"id":"5","food":"potato","Amount":"700","condition":"paid"}]}';

$arr = json_decode($response, true);
echo $arr['items'][1]['food']; // beans
```

https://3v4l.org/RiqSo

---

If you need to remove the unwanted `\` you can use stripslashes.

```
$arr = json_decode(stripslashes($response), true);
```

https://3v4l.org/WslYh

---

To replicate the error you get you need to do the following:

```
$response = '{"items":
     [{"id":"1","food":"rice","Amount":"100","condition":"paid"},\
      {"id":"2","food":"beans","Amount":"200","condition":"paid"},\
      {"id":"3","food":"yam","Amount":"50","condition":"not paid"},\
      {"id":"4","food":"tomatoes","Amount":"100","condition":"paid"},\
      {"id":"5","food":"potato","Amount":"700","condition":"paid"}]}';

$arr = (string)json_decode($response, true); // json_decode returns NULL and the string cast makes it "NULL"
echo $arr['items'][1]['food']; // Warning: Illegal string offset 'items'
// or
echo $response['items'][1]['food']; // Warning: Illegal string offset 'items'
```

Comment: Thank you Andreas! With the slashes in place, the now working code returns an empty value. The error itself was caused by me missing the ", true" part when decoding. Why was that so important?

Comment: The true tells json_decode how to format the output, either as an array (true) or as an object (false). The error is because json_decode can't decode an array that is invalid and returns `NULL`. So when $response is `NULL` there is no `[items]` and that is why the parser says *"Illegal string offset 'items'*

Comment: I tried it both ways as a learning exercise and I feel pretty good now! Thank you.

Comment: Yes. If you want to use it as an object then you need to use `->` between the items

Comment: Andreas, the code no longer works when I use the response from curl_exec()

Comment: Any reason why you need curl? I usually use file_get_contents if I can. Only when I need to spoof agent I use Curl.

Comment: This is my first attempt at getting data from an API, so I just went with Curl. I'll do a quick search for file_get_contents now, is it pretty straight forward?

Comment: I would say so. But essentially both should return the string. `$response = file_get_contents($URL);` What does the $response contain? Make sure to var_dump to make sure there is no spaces or something that creates the error

Comment: That's the funny thing. I did var_dump and the output was identical to the food example I had above?? That's why I thought it would just work

Comment: With or without `\\`? Try the stripslashes code and see if that works.

Comment: Oh jeez, sorry mate, I just needed to make sure the keys were case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$response = '{"items":
     [{"id":"1","food":"rice","Amount":"100","condition":"paid"},
      {"id":"2","food":"beans","Amount":"200","condition":"paid"},
      {"id":"3","food":"yam","Amount":"50","condition":"not paid"},
      {"id":"4","food":"tomatoes","Amount":"100","condition":"paid"},
      {"id":"5","food":"potato","Amount":"700","condition":"paid"}]}';

$response_json = json_decode($response);
echo $response_json->items[2]->food.' | '.$response_json->items[2]->condition;

output : yam | not paid
```

Comment: Yeah that works well. I prefer to use arrays so I just needed to add the 'true' parameter to my json_decode.

Answer (score 1):

decode your string into json using `json_decode`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php refer this link for more infomation

Comment: Sorry but I get the error whether I decode it or not.

Comment: Can't you keep an array with keys and decode it to json. That works pretty cool.

Comment: json_decode($response, true); - I was missing the true part :(

Comment: Happy to hear that you've figured it out :-)

Answer (score 1):

**The data which you accessing it is in json format. So first you have to convert it into normal Array using `json_decode();`**

Here is the code how.

```
$response = json_decode($response, true);
```

Now it is array. So can access its data like this way.

```
echo $response['items'][1]['food'];
```

Output :

```
beans
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert first json into array to using `json_decode()` function.

```
$response = '{"items":
     [{"id":"1","food":"rice","Amount":"100","condition":"paid"},
      {"id":"2","food":"beans","Amount":"200","condition":"paid"},
      {"id":"3","food":"yam","Amount":"50","condition":"not paid"},
      {"id":"4","food":"tomatoes","Amount":"100","condition":"paid"},
      {"id":"5","food":"potato","Amount":"700","condition":"paid"}]}';

$getarray = json_decode($response);

echo $getarray->items[0]->food;
```